# Using np.argpartition to index values in a multidimensional array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array like this one:

```
>>> a = np.arange(60).reshape([3,4,5])
>>> a
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]],

       [[20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
        [25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
        [30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
        [35, 36, 37, 38, 39]],

       [[40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
        [45, 46, 47, 48, 49],
        [50, 51, 52, 53, 54],
        [55, 56, 57, 58, 59]]])
```

And I want to retrieve the top k values along one of the dimensions. For example's sake I'll choose k=2 and along the middle dimension.

I've tried using `argpartition` and it seems to do the right thing, but I'm having trouble using it's output to retrieve the values from the original array. Here's how I'm using argpartition:

```
>>> indices = np.argpartition(a, 2, axis=1)
>>> indices
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]]])

>>> indices[:,-2:,:]
array([[[2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]],

       [[2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]],

       [[2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]]])
```

But I've not been able to get the values out by slicing using these indices.

```
>>> a[:,indices[:,-2:,:],:].shape
(3, 3, 2, 5, 5)
```

I am expecting to see an array of shape `(3,2,5)` (as I'm looking for the top-2 along the middle axis) that I imagine looks something like this:

```
>>> magic_output
array([[[10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]],

       [[30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
        [35, 36, 37, 38, 39]],

       [[50, 51, 52, 53, 54],
        [55, 56, 57, 58, 59]]])
```

How can I access the values using the indices from `argpartition`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well `np.argpartition` gets the smallest `k` indices. So, to get the top `k` indices, we need to use negated input array along the desired axis. Then, we need to use these indices to index into that axis using `NumPy's advanced-indexing` and have the desired output.

Thus, the implementation would be -

```
k = 2
m,n = a.shape[0], a.shape[2]
idx = np.argpartition(-a,k,axis=1)[:,k-1::-1]
out = a[np.arange(m)[:,None,None], idx, np.arange(n)]
```

Sample run -

1) Input :

```
In [180]: a
Out[180]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]],

       [[20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
        [25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
        [30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
        [35, 36, 37, 38, 39]],

       [[40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
        [45, 46, 47, 48, 49],
        [50, 51, 52, 53, 54],
        [55, 56, 57, 58, 59]]])
```

2) Proposed codes :

```
In [206]: k = 2
     ...: m,n = a.shape[0], a.shape[2]
     ...: idx = np.argpartition(-a,k,axis=1)[:,k-1::-1]
     ...: out = a[np.arange(m)[:,None,None], idx, np.arange(n)]
     ...:
```

3) Check back intermediate results and output :

```
In [207]: idx
Out[207]: 
array([[[2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]],

       [[2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]],

       [[2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]]])

In [208]: out
Out[208]: 
array([[[10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]],

       [[30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
        [35, 36, 37, 38, 39]],

       [[50, 51, 52, 53, 54],
        [55, 56, 57, 58, 59]]])
```

Comment: Thanks! Does `argpartition` need to work on a negated input, or can you use a negative `kth` parameter?

Comment: @MarkMcDonald Well I just ran few tests and basically it sorts the rest of the elements. So, if `k` is a small number, it makes sense to use negative of input array and then use `np.argpartition`, as shown in this post. Unless `k` is almost as long as the length of that axis itself, I would say stick to negating array method.

Comment: There is a simpler way for effectively getting top `k` indices, do:
`np.argpartition(a, -k, axis=1)[:, -k:]`
Essentially partition pivoted at `-k` position

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `argpartition` just sort your array along the second axis using `np.sort()` and choose the last 2 items from that axis:

```
np.sort(a, 2)[:, -2:, ]
```

Here is an example on shuffled version of your array:

```
In [15]: np.random.shuffle(a)

In [16]: a
Out[16]: 
array([[[40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
        [45, 46, 47, 48, 49],
        [50, 51, 52, 53, 54],
        [55, 56, 57, 58, 59]],

       [[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]],

       [[20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
        [25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
        [30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
        [35, 36, 37, 38, 39]]])

In [17]: np.sort(a, 2)[:, -2:, ]
Out[17]: 
array([[[50, 51, 52, 53, 54],
        [55, 56, 57, 58, 59]],

       [[10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]],

       [[30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
        [35, 36, 37, 38, 39]]])
```

Comment: Well we might need `argpartition` for efficiency purposes, specially for arrays with a longer axis along the desired one.

Comment: The reason behind argpartition is that I need the indices. I have two arrays to sort based on the values in one.